# Remove excess delimiter from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm using Python 3 to clean up a `CSV` file that sometimes has four entries per line. For some reason the `datalogger` didn't insert a new line, and this happened periodically, not sure why.

So I'm trying to remove bad characters from the `CSV` and have had success, but the lines with four entries instead of two I wanted to find the delimiter and replace it with a new line.

Sounds simple enough, but I don't possess the *code-fu*, and I'm wondering if anyone could help. :)
thanks

```
import csv 


with open('outty1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["Date", "Temperature", "Humidity"])

text = open("temperature.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("Ã¿Ã¿", ",")


for i in text:
    if i.count(',')>1:
        text.replace(",", "/n")

x = open("outty1.csv","a")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

A sample of the temperature log before parsing it :) .

```
1629881977,24.27
1629882037,24.28ÿÿ1629882097,24.29
1629882157,24.31ÿÿ1629882217,23.52
1629882277,23.38ÿÿ1629882337,23.72
1629882397,23.87ÿÿ1629882457,23.92
1629882517,23.98ÿÿ1629882577,24.02
1629882637,24.08ÿÿ1629882697,24.12
1629882757,24.15
1629882817,24.19
1629882877,24.24
1629882937,24.31
1629882997,24.36
1629883057,24.40
1629883117,24.44
1629883177,24.38
1629883237,24.50
1629883298,24.60
1629883358,24.72
1629883418,24.88
1629883478,25.05
1629883538,25.23
1629883598,25.42
1629883658,25.63ÿÿ1629883718,25.85
1629883778,26.08ÿÿ1629883838,26.31
1629883898,26.53ÿÿ1629883958,26.74
1629884018,26.96ÿÿ1629884078,27.12
1629884138,27.26ÿÿ1629884198,27.38
1629884258,27.48ÿÿ1629884318,27.56
1629884378,27.63ÿÿ1629884438,27.69
1629884498,27.73.
```

This is my progress once I run the program

```
Date,Temperature,Humidity
1629881977,24.27
1629882037,24.28,1629882097,24.29
1629882157,24.31,1629882217,23.52
1629882277,23.38,1629882337,23.72
1629882397,23.87,1629882457,23.92
1629882517,23.98,1629882577,24.02
1629882637,24.08,1629882697,24.12
1629882757,24.15
1629882817,24.19
1629882877,24.24
1629882937,24.31
1629882997,24.36
1629883057,24.40
1629883117,24.44
1629883177,24.38
1629883237,24.50
1629883298,24.60
1629883358,24.72
1629883418,24.88
1629883478,25.05
1629883538,25.23
1629883598,25.42
1629883658,25.63,1629883718,25.85
1629883778,26.08,1629883838,26.31
1629883898,26.53,1629883958,26.74
1629884018,26.96,1629884078,27.12
1629884138,27.26,1629884198,27.38
1629884258,27.48,1629884318,27.56
1629884378,27.63,1629884438,27.69
1629884498,27.73
```

and the fixed sample output, I saw the answer once I pasted the input and compared the out put LOL :)

```
Date,Temperature,Humidity
1629881977,24.27
1629882037,24.28
1629882097,24.29
1629882157,24.31
1629882217,23.52
1629882277,23.38
1629882337,23.72
1629882397,23.87
1629882457,23.92
1629882517,23.98
1629882577,24.02
1629882637,24.08
1629882697,24.12
1629882757,24.15
1629882817,24.19
1629882877,24.24
1629882937,24.31
1629882997,24.36
1629883057,24.40
1629883117,24.44
1629883177,24.38
1629883237,24.50
1629883298,24.60
1629883358,24.72
1629883418,24.88
1629883478,25.05
1629883538,25.23
1629883598,25.42
1629883658,25.63
1629883718,25.85
1629883778,26.08
1629883838,26.31
1629883898,26.53
1629883958,26.74
1629884018,26.96
1629884078,27.12
1629884138,27.26
1629884198,27.38
1629884258,27.48
1629884318,27.56
1629884378,27.63
1629884438,27.69
1629884498,27.73
1629884558,27.75
```

the old code

```
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("Ã¿Ã¿", ",")
```

the new code

```
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("Ã¿Ã¿", "\n")
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the CSV file, including problematic entries?

Comment: Added the output then saw the solution. I had already removed the junk, but didn't realise I was inserting the extra comma. I replaced the "," with "\n" and I have what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for another option to consider, here's something to try:

```
data = """1629881977,24.27
1629882037,24.28ÿÿ1629882097,24.29
1629882757,24.15
"""

# spliting on the garbage chars has a side-effect of removing them
a = data.split('ÿÿ')

# then simply join() to reassemble the original data
b = '\n'.join(a)
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
fixed_data = '\n'.join(data.split('ÿÿ'))
```

Comment: I like it, always open to learning new tricks :)